# Jetpack compose function is not getting updated when changing the value of livedata in viewmodel

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose, mutablelivedata

I am trying jetpack compose with ViewModel. Whenever the user clicks on some item I want to select that item and deselect everything else. The problem is if I try to manipulate the same mutable list with the new value it is not working. But if I try it with the new list it is working fine. Please check the snapshot of the code for more clarification.

This is my ViewModel.

```
private var _pagerItems = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<PagerItem>>()

val pagerItems: LiveData<ArrayList<PagerItem>> = _pagerItems

init {
    _pagerItems.value = arrayListOf(
        PagerItem(pagerTitle = "Home", isSelected = true),
        PagerItem(pagerTitle = "TVShows", isSelected = false),
        PagerItem(pagerTitle = "Movies", isSelected = false),
        PagerItem(pagerTitle = "Kids", isSelected = false),
    )
}

fun onPagerItemSelected(pagerItem: PagerItem) {

    val list = arrayListOf(
        PagerItem(pagerTitle = "Home", isSelected = true),
        PagerItem(pagerTitle = "TVShows", isSelected = false),
        PagerItem(pagerTitle = "Movies", isSelected = false),
        PagerItem(pagerTitle = "Kids", isSelected = false),
    )

    list.forEach {
        it.isSelected = it.pagerTitle.equals(pagerItem.pagerTitle, true)
    }

    _pagerItems.value = list
    
}
```

And this is my compose function.

```
val list: ArrayList<PagerItem> by
mainActivityViewModel.pagerItems.observeAsState(arrayListOf())

Row(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(top = 16.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
) {

    for (item in list) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { mainActivityViewModel.onPagerItemSelected(item) },
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

            Text(
                text = item.pagerTitle,
                style = TextStyle(color = animateColorAsState(targetValue = if (item.isSelected) Color.White else Color.Gray).value),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
            )

            Divider(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(
                        color = animateColorAsState(
                            targetValue = if (item.isSelected) Color.White else Color.Transparent
                        ).value
                    )
                    .height(2.dp)
                    .width(80.dp)
            )
        }

    }
}
```

Now, whenever the user clicks on the item it is calling the ViewModel method to update the list.
The above code for ViewModel is working fine because I am creating a new ArrayList. However, if I try to manipulate the existing mutable live data it is not working.

```
fun onPagerItemSelected(pagerItem: PagerItem) {

    val updatedList = arrayListOf<PagerItem>()

    updatedList.addAll(_pagerItems.value ?: arrayListOf())

    _pagerItems.value?.forEach {
        it.isSelected = pagerItem.pagerTitle.equals(it.pagerTitle, true)
    }

    _pagerItems.value = updatedList
}
```

or

```
fun onPagerItemSelected(pagerItem: PagerItem) {

    _pagerItems.value?.forEach {
        it.isSelected = pagerItem.pagerTitle.equals(it.pagerTitle, true)
    }
}
```

above two examples are not causing the recomposition of the function. Even though, the list is getting updated.

Comment: Yeah i had face this too. when I update the list and set that value again. change that `PagerItem` to data class and use copy methond

Comment: @RofieSagara, PagerItem is indeed a data class.